# Add input's errors in array with for

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have one problem in PHP code. It did not give me whatever output. Where my mistake?

```
if (isset($_POST['regBtn'])) {
    $fname = strip_tags(trim($_POST['fname']));
    $lname = strip_tags(trim($_POST['lname']));
    $email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));
    $password = strip_tags(trim($_POST['password']));
    $errMsg = array();
    for($i=0; $i<=3;$i++) {
    if (strlen($fname) < 0) {
        $errMsg[$i] = "Գրեք Ձեր անունը ամբողջությամբ։";
    } elseif (strlen ($lname) <0) {
        $errMsg[$i] = "Գրեք Ձեր ազգանունը ամբողջությամբ";
    } elseif (strlen($email) < 0) {
        $errMsg[$i] = "Գրեք Ձեր էլ․ հասցեն";
    } elseif (strlen($password) < 6) {
        $errMsg = "Գաղտնաբառը պետք է պարունակի առնվազն 6 նիշ";
    } }
    var_dump ($errMsg); 
 }
else {


}
```

Comment: Why do you even have the `for` loop?  It makes no sense.

Comment: where are you printing out an error message? your example shows you creating them but we don't see where you're printing them

Comment: with this line i printing var_dump ($errMsg);

Comment: Are you sure it's hitting the if block? Maybe it's hitting the else block.

Comment: That would overwrite the indexed strings. What you probably want is `$errMsg[] = "...";` and then a `foreach` *afterwards* to echo the collected messages.

Comment: When will `strlen` be LESS than 0? Hint... never...

Comment: Yeah! it going in else :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems here, assuming that you have a form input with `name="regBtn"` which is **required** for this code to run:

1. `strlen` will not be `< 0` though it may be `0`.  Use `empty` or a number greater than `0` if needed.
2. `elseif` will only execute if the `if` fails so just use `if`.
3. No need to loop, just use multiple `if` blocks and dynamically append to the error array `[]`.

---

```
if (isset($_POST['regBtn'])) {
    $fname = strip_tags(trim($_POST['fname']));
    $lname = strip_tags(trim($_POST['lname']));
    $email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));
    $password = strip_tags(trim($_POST['password']));
    $errMsg = array();

    if (empty($fname)) { // or use strlen < 2 or < 3 or whatever like $password
        $errMsg[] = "Գրեք Ձեր անունը ամբողջությամբ։";
    }
    if (empty($lname)) {
        $errMsg[] = "Գրեք Ձեր ազգանունը ամբողջությամբ";
    }
    if (empty($email)) {
        $errMsg[] = "Գրեք Ձեր էլ․ հասցեն";
    }
    if (strlen($password) < 6) {
        $errMsg[] = "Գաղտնաբառը պետք է պարունակի առնվազն 6 նիշ";
    }
    var_dump ($errMsg); 
 }
```

Also, you probably want to `trim` after `strip_tags` in case it leaves space(s):

```
$fname = trim(strip_tags($_POST['fname']));
```